# JavaScript String Replace all

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I have the following string and I want to replace all special characters of a string.

```
let data = "`test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]\|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()`"
```

Special characters:

```
let spcial=[".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\"];
```

final output:

```
test@#\\$demo%\\^here\\[sf\\.s\\]\\\\\|demo\\{delata\\}\\*testing\\?\\+\\$\\^\\(\\)
```

In short, I want to add \ in front of a special character so How I can do it?

Comment: 6 snippets proposed. Solutions explained. Have you check them?

Comment: Please consider the solutions proposed, your interaction with these responses could help many other people with similar issues. Thanks in advance Suraj Dalvi.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = "`test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]\\|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()`"
let spcial=[".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\\"]

const res = data.split("").map(ch => spcial.includes(ch) ? "\\\\" + ch : ch).join("")

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Want to add "\\" before each keyword which is the part of the array. and also my string consists "s]\|" so want to add "\\" for each character.

Comment: yes but stall for "\|demo" I want "\\\\\|demo" want to consider "\" which is present in string

Comment: It's because "\|" is recognized as "|". You can change it to "\\|demo"

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = "`test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]\|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()`"
let spcial=[".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\\"]    
for (let c of data) {
  if(spcial.includes(c) ) {
    data = data.replace(c, '\\'+c)
  }
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
str = "test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]\|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()";
const spcial=[".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\\"];
spcial.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(value) {
  str = str.replaceAll(value, "\\" + value);
}

console.log(str)
```

Comment: it giving error like str.replaceAll is not a function

Comment: @SurajDalvi Which environment / Browser is your JS running? The function is already available at JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll do you good in the long run to learn some Regular Expressions (regex/regexp). A regular expression that I've used to find special characters is `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g`. If you use the `replace` method with a callback function, you can take the matched special character `m` and be able to replace it with `\\${m}`.

Read more about RegEx here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Read more about `replace` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

To do exactly what you want to have above, this would be a regex implementation:

```
const data = "`test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()`";
const specialCharacters = /\.|\+|\*|\?|\^|\$|\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\}|\||\\/g;
const output = data.replace(specialCharacters, (m) => `\\${m}`);

console.log(output);
```

I recommend checking for more special characters.

```js
const data = "`test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()`";
const output = data.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, (m) => `\\${m}`);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I don't have much idea about regex but is any direct regex present to add \\ before specified characters
let spcial=[".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\"];

Comment: Yes, you would use `/\.|\+|\*|\?|\^|\$|\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\}|\||\\/g`, but I don't recommend arbitrarily cherry picking special characters unless you're entirely sure those are the only special characters you want to consider.

Comment: yes, I want to consider only these characters. if possible can you please share actual  replace syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = "`test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]\|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()`";
let special=[".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\\"];
let [...chars] = data;
chars = chars.map(char => {
    if (special.includes(char)) return `\\${char}`;
    return char;
}
data = chars.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1: From a fixed list of special chars

You can replace it all at once, with a regular expression like this:

```js
let data = "test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]\|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()";

let replaced = data.replace(/[\.\+\*\?\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\|\\]/g, '\\$&');

console.log(replaced);
```

Note that the special chars are listed, escaped with a backslash, inside the regular expression.
If you want to learn more about how this works, take a look [here, in the "Explain" section](https://regexr.com/5k9bb).

## Approach 2: From a dynamic list of special chars

If you want to build this regular expression dynamically from an array, you can do it like this:

```js
let data = "test@#$demo%^here[sf.s]\|demo{delata}*testing?+$^()";
let specialChars = [".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\\"];

let regexp = new RegExp(`[\\${specialChars.join('\\')}]`, 'g');
let replaced = data.replace(regexp, '\\$&');

console.log(replaced);
```

### Result

in both examples the result will be:

```
test@#\$demo%\^here\[sf\.s\]\|demo\{delata\}\*testing\?\+\$\^\(\)
```

Using a global replace (denoted by `g` at the end), you can replace all characters at once, without need for loops.